# Where to get IPA files for 32-bit iPad Mini

Tags: download, application, 32bit, ios

I have an old iPad Mini (2013 model)
that I thought to resurrect as a screen for a Raspberry Pi with VNC Viewer,
but when I try to download the app (or any app) via App Store
I get an error with "the app is not compatible with your iPad". 
I dig a bit and I found that such model has 32-bit architecture
and that most apps are no longer supporting those builds. 
Is there any place, like an archive,
where I can get such 32-bit versions of the apps
(mainly VNC, but if I get the change of getting some others, then better)? 
If so, how could I install them?

For reference,

> A **.ipa** file is an iOS and iPadOS application archive file
> which stores an iOS/iPadOS app.

— [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.ipa)

Answer (score 0):

You'll likely need to jailbreak your device, but that'll be pretty easy. 
*(I love it that people want to repurpose old devices and do it myself, too,
so I am also on the lookout for 32-bit IPAs.)* 
You may look through [the vnc-viewer-ipa-collection directory listing
at the Internet Archive](https://archive.org/download/vnc-viewer-ipa-collection) and see if there's an IPA supporting iOS 10
(which is what you probably use).

I also found [the 17,000+ IPA Collection • iPhoneOS Obscura Project
at the Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/iOSObscura). 
There might be an app there that you could need or would like to use.